# zfs and solaris11: how to reduce ram consumption?

Tags: solaris, zfs

```
sudo echo ::memstat | sudo mdb -k
Usage Type/Subtype                      Pages    Bytes  %Tot  %Tot/%Subt
---------------------------- ---------------- -------- ----- -----------
Kernel                                 291425     1.1g 17.5%
ZFS                                    844447     3.2g 50.7%
```

zfs is over 3G,but I have set ARC to consume max 2G

```
cat /etc/system
set zfs:zfs_arc_max = 2147483648
set zfs:zfs_arc_min = 1073741824
```

I have reboot of course.

Version is 11.4 beta

Comment: Which version of Solaris 11?

Comment: Version is 11.4 beta

Comment: See this:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54818/chapterzfs-3.html#scrolltoc  `zfs_arc_max` appears to have been deprecated in favor of some amorphous `user_reserve_hint_pct`. Seems like they still have some of the we-know-better-than-everyone-else "ZFS is ***ALWAYS*** consistent on disk so no `fsck` will ***EVER*** be needed!!!!" developers running things...  :-/  That attitude from Sun's original ZFS implementation was misguided and misplaced 10+ years ago - it's a shame it appears to still live on.

Comment: Thanks. Add as answer please, so I can close and vote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zfs_arc_max` has apparently been deprecated.  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54818/chapterzfs-3.html#scrolltoc:

> **ZFS Memory Management Parameters**
>
> This section describes parameters related to ZFS memory management.
>
> **user_reserve_hint_pct**
>
> **Description**
>
> Informs the system about how much memory is reserved for application
>   use, and therefore limits how much memory can be used by the ZFS ARC
>   cache as the cache increases over time.
>
> By means of this parameter, administrators can maintain a large
>   reserve of available free memory for future application demands. The
>   user_reserve_hint_pct parameter is intended to be used in place of the
>   zfs_arc_max parameter to restrict the growth of the ZFS ARC cache.
>
> Note -  Review Document 1663862.1, Memory Management Between ZFS and
>   Applications in Oracle Solaris 11.2, in My Oracle Support (MOS) for
>   guidance in tuning this parameter. Data Type
>
> Unsigned Integer (64-bit)
>
> **Default**
>
> 0
>
> If a dedicated system is used to run a set of applications with a
>   known memory footprint, set the parameter to the value of that
>   footprint, such as the sum of the SGA of Oracle database.
>
> To assign a value to the parameter, run the script that is provided in
>   Document 1663862.1 in My Oracle Support (MOS). To make the tuning
>   persistent across reboots, refer to script output for instructions
>   about using –p option.
>
> **Range**
>
> 0-99
>
> **Units**
>
> Percent
>
> **Dynamic**
>
> Yes
>
> You can adjust the setting of this parameter dynamically on a running
>   system.
>
> **When to Change**
>
> For upward adjustments, increase the value if the initial value is
>   determined to be insufficient over time for application requirements,
>   or if application demand increases on the system. Perform this
>   adjustment only within a scheduled system maintenance window. After
>   you have changed the value, reboot the system.
>
> For downward adjustments, decrease the value if allowed by application
>   requirements. Make sure to use decrease the value only by small
>   amounts, no greater than 5% at a time.
>
> **Commitment Level**
>
> Unstable
>
> ...
>
> **zfs_arc_max**
>
> Description
>
> Determines the maximum size of the ZFS Adaptive Replacement Cache
>   (ARC). **However, see `user_reserve_hint_pct`**.

In my opinion, this is a huge step backwards.  A hard limit is replaced with a mere "hint".  There can be very, very, very good reasons for a **hard** limit.

(I'm wondering if there really is an undocumented ARC hard limit.  Sun/Oracle has a history of doing things like that with ZFS.  "ZFS is always consistent on disk!  You don't need `fsck` or any debugging tools.  No, you don't.  WE SAID YOU DON'T. **WHY OH WHY WON'T YOU BELIEVE US?!?!** Oh, ummm, ahhh, yeah, here's `zdb`.  We've been using it internally for years so it's pretty mature...")

Comment: Oh, user_reserve_hint_pct is quite a hard limit. It just limits something different. It limits the memory consumed by the kernel and it has an important advantage about the old way, it's dynamic and it can be changed while the system is running. As the ARC is at the moment the only thing that can shrink on user demand, you limit the ARC by proxy. At the end it's the more correct way, you limit ARC to ensure enough memory for the application, not because you want a certain size of ZFS ARC.

Comment: Regarding your ZFS rant: You should tell the other part of the "No ZFS error checking"-story. The idea is that any generic repair mechanism is just able to force the filesystem into a state based on a set of assumption, that may be mountable but may destroy a lot of data on the way. When there is a bug that  does damage to the on-disk state it should repair the on-disk state with the knowledge of the bug at every read or write  and do it without sending a lot of data into lost+found.

Comment: @c0t0d0s0 *Oh, user_reserve_hint_pct is quite a hard limit.* Then why is it called a "hint"? Why not just document `zfs_arc_max` and make it dynamic?  Do you have access to the source code?  And the ZFS "always consistent on disk" marketing hype, even if possible, completely depends upon there not being any bugs in the code.  The very fact that `zdb` secretly existed for **years** before becoming public is proof those claims were known to be lies when they were made:  if ZFS is "always consistent on disk", why does `zdb` even *exist*? That claim generated much laughter when ZFS debuted.